# Bug with <pre><code> tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting, editor

When I try to use the `<pre><code>` tags in my answer, it gives me this error:

[image: Screenshot]

on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29168526/3763850

As you can see in the edit history, another user used these tags just fine before, but when I edited after him, I got this error.

**Edit**

The reason why I considered this a bug is that the screenshot is a reproduction of the issue, originally I only wanted to append the second code part and I did so with the spaces as instructed, but it shows that exact error message on the other user's code.

I find it odd that there's no response if it happens to be a reputation issue, and I also find it awkward that lower rep users have to delete previous user's code to be able to submit edits.

Comment: Why are you using those instead of backticks (`\``)?  Or four space indentation?

Comment: @Makoto It looked like the editor that used them was trying to format the code inside the block, i.e. bolding a line of the code. Doing so requires the <pre><code> blocks, from what I've seen. The OP here then tried to edit their answer and received the error after adding another code block.

Comment: @Makoto it's exactly as Kendra said. I assume the tags also exist for the purpose of being able to format the code text.

Answer (score 12):

This check is predicated on reputation. For Stack Overflow, it stops running once you've earned 500 reputation points.

Your example does a pretty good job of illustrating the *reason* for this: the editor you were copying used that markup to emphasize part of the code (the bit between `<strong>` tags), an aspect of the edit which you overlooked entirely.

This should be considered an advanced use of formatting. Some experienced users go all-out, including various forms of emphasis, links in their code comments, etc. But most new users struggle to get even basic code formatting (the sort [triggered by just indenting the block 4 spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)) working properly. Best to stay away from mixing HTML markup with Markdown until you know what you're doing.

Comment: Oh, I left them out just to reproduce the bugg. If it is indeed as you say that it's a rep thing, then I can understand it, it's just awkward that I have to remove the previous editer's code in order to make edits myself as a lower rep user.

Comment: Shog, she removed those styles because she couldn't submit with them. (Hence why I urged her to submit this bug). The question is, why, if code is formatted correctly, and especially if it was edited by a high rep user (and the lower rep user is just editing), will a low rep user get the error, despite nothing really being wrong.

Comment: @Madara: Nothing wrong? The `</pre></code>` tags are incorrectly nested in the screenshot.

Comment: That - editing other parts of a high-rep edited post failing the check - should be the bug report then, @Madara. That said, I would caution you against this technique when editing others' posts in the future, for the reasons I outlined here.

Answer (score 1):

I [just managed to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29168526/4) by only changing the first block around.

Normally I stay away from using HTML tags to format code, but there are rare cases when they make sense to use.  In those cases, I'd try to scope them out as narrowly as possible; only use them when it makes contextual sense to do so.

Your second code block has no additional formatting or style required, so it makes no sense to try to force it in there.

Comment: The issue lies with that even though I only wanted to add the second block, I had to remove his code in order to submit my own. I think it's a kinda awkward thing if it is intentional that only a certain amout of rep users can use those tags.

Also, shouldn't the error message at least tell me I'm too low rep to submit the code?