# Why does Stack Overflow block answers because of code formatting issues?

Tags: support

I have a long detailed answer to a question that I spend considerable time on only to discover that I cannot format it to satisfy the question submission nanny.  And it does not matter whether I apply the formatting as requested by the gatekeeper or remove it.  The section, which is essential to the answer, and which was contained in an explicit `<pre></pre>` block anyway, does not pass the edit check.  So I have necessarily discarded it and that bit of help is permanently gone.

I do not see why a preformatted block is being checked for formatting anyway.

```
cat /etc/yum.repos.d/LocalFile.repo
# LocalFile.repo
#
#  This repo is used with a local filesystem repo.
#
# To use this repo place the rpm package in /root/RPMS/yum.repo/Packages.
# Then run: createrepo --database --update /root/RPMS/yum.repo.
#
# To use:
#  yum --enablerepo=localfile [command]
#  
# or to use only ONLY this repo, do this:
#
#  yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=localfile [command]

[localfile]
baseurl=file:///root/RPMS/yum.repo
name=CentOS-$releasever - Local Filesystem repo

# Before persistently enabling this repo see the priority note below.
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0

# When this repo is enabled all packages in repos with priority>5
# will not be updated even when they have a more recent version.
# Be careful with this.
priority=5
```

Comment: Why are you using `<pre>` blocks anyway?  What requirement do you have of the that can't be satisfied by backticks or four-space indentation?

Comment: I would love to show it, but the site will not accept it. So, How do I show it? And your comment begs the issue without first determining if there just might be a problem with the site. A bit hasty in my opinion.

Comment: You *could* put the entire contents of it here in a code format so we could evaluate it.  Then we'd be able to at least see issues with your raw formatting.

Comment: Why not post an example?

Comment: As for my comment being a bit hasty:  in the last four or so years of using the site, I've seen formatting problems crop up...maybe six or seven times.  I don't think it's the site, but I could be swayed.

Comment: Ok: '    cat /etc/yum.repos.d/LocalFile.repo
    # LocalFile.repo
    #
    #  This repo is used with a local filesystem repo.
    #'

Comment: Of course, now all the line breaks are gone.

Comment: Then why didn't you put it in the question instead of a comment? See the little 'edit' link? That'll do it for you...

Comment: And this is incomplete since the comments are limited in size

Comment: So, it accepts it here but not in the answer to the question itself.

Comment: Again, why are you using <pre>?

Comment: Because whether I use pre or not I get a submission error.  Is there something about this problem that I cannot make clear?  it does not matter to the gatekeeper wheter or not pre/pre are present or absent, or the code is indented 4 spaces or not.  I get the same code formatting error.  I only used tjhe per/pre to get around the original problem.

Comment: Nope. Demonstrated below. You are not using the editor correctly and you are complaining about the results.

Comment: Related:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291141/1079354  - I recalled Shog9 having some things to say about this a while ago...It may be due to one's reputation.

Comment: So, essentially I cannot provide the answer until I reach 500 reputation.  Good to know. if I ever get that high.

Comment: You could. If you stop using HTML tags mixed with markdown. Which is what everyone keeps telling you.

Comment: And I am use=ing the editor exactly as the gatekeeper suggests.  it just does not work as you imagine it does.  The presence or absence of the pre block has no effect on what the gatekeeper does with this code block and is a distraction from the real problem.

Comment: ...No, that's not it **at all**.  It's just that you're using exotic HTML and you *really* shouldn't be doing that yet.  If you want to answer, that's fine; I can help you by editing it in there. If you *don't*, then please don't throw a tantrum because you think the site is broken and we're explaining to you that it isn't, and you really shouldn't be formatting code that way.

Comment: "The presence or absence of the pre block has no effect and is a distraction from the real problem." - Also, the sky is green and I am a giant moth.

Comment: Look if I take out the pre block, which is the only 'exotic' html present then I get the same error.  The use of pre only occurred after the indenting did not change the gatekeeper result.

Comment: Nope. That is demonstrated as untrue below.

Comment: So why haven't you linked to the post yet?  I keep telling you that I could edit it in...then I could see what's really going on.  Also: I hope you're not just pasting the code as the canonical answer, since that'd trip up a quality filter, not a formatting filter.

Comment: Big surprise, works fine now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33439452/5640

Comment: So now I resubmit the same answer and I instead of an error I get a capcha prompt which, when answered, allows the answer.  I am not at all clear on what is going on here.

Comment: Assuming it's your latest answer, the problem was simply that you need *two* levels of indentation (8 spaces) at the start of each line if your code block is within a numbered/bulleted list.

Comment: Might help if you RTFM, since you appear to have a lot of formatting issues: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Or do you *actually* want an answer for your title question?

Comment: Actually, I would.  The down-voting and technical answers to the problem came as a bit of a surprise and I admit to being side-tracked into dealing with that.  I just wanted to know why a pre block would be considered a formatting error.  I have used markdown in lots of communities and I often find the pre block avoids a lot of fiddlelyness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With numbered/bulleted lists, your code blocks need two levels (eight spaces) of indentation at the start of every line. This is covered (albeit not particularly explicitly) in the [editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists):

> To put other Markdown blocks in a list; just indent four spaces for each nesting level

Demo:

1. This only has four leading spaces:

   hello world
2. This has eight leading spaces:

   ```
   hello world
   ```

Sadly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> or the `{}` button don't help you with this; I find the easiest way is to paste in the code and indent it one level (all relative to the code block, so it's readable!):

```
    hello world
```

add an extra line immediately before it with no indentation:

```
foo
    hello world
```

apply an indent to the whole lot:

```
    foo 
        hello world
```

then delete the first line again.

---

- For what it's worth, `<pre>` in lists works fine too, but without the leading indent:

```
hello world
```

- Second list item

Comment: The double indent requirement is data that I do not see in the RTFM reference given above and is not something that would occur to me otherwise.  But this is the answer to the formatting problem.

Comment: @JamesB.Byrne yes, I'm not sure the collision of lists and code blocks is documented

Comment: @jonrsharpe While I have used the same trick you described for indenting more than 4 spaces in the editor, surely you must agree that it's just a hacky workaround to an actual problem. Ctrl+K should be more context-aware.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to work *just fine* without the `<pre>` tags.  I would *strongly* discourage their use from now on, since the four-space indentation covers your general use case.

```
cat /etc/yum.repos.d/LocalFile.repo
# LocalFile.repo
#
#  This repo is used with a local filesystem repo.
#
# To use this repo place the rpm package in /root/RPMS/yum.repo/Packages.
# Then run: createrepo --database --update /root/RPMS/yum.repo.
#
# To use:
#  yum --enablerepo=localfile [command]
#  
# or to use only ONLY this repo, do this:
#
#  yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=localfile [command]

[localfile]
baseurl=file:///root/RPMS/yum.repo
name=CentOS-$releasever - Local Filesystem repo

# Before persistently enabling this repo see the priority note below.
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0

# When this repo is enabled all packages in repos with priority>5
# will not be updated even when they have a more recent version.
# Be careful with this.
priority=5
```

Comment: It works here.  Not where I need it to work.

Comment: Take me to the post.  I could probably edit it in.