# Doesn't formatting <b> tags inside a <pre> tag

Tags: bug, code-formatting, formatting

Sometimes I write answers within the `<pre>...</pre>` tag to get more control over formatting the answers. Usually, I do this with the code-snippets, which may be required some emphasis.

In the below snippet, I want to emphasize the expression `str(getattr(self, field.name))` and thus I wrote the answer as below,

```
<pre><code>class HelperClass:
    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field, <b>str(getattr(self, field.name))</b>) for field in self._meta.fields]</code></pre>
```

But, the *bold* formatting doesn't appear.

[image]

**Note**: I/We can see the formatted code block in the [*"edit/preview mode"*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgrGj.png)

Is this a bug? Or was this feature removed in some release?

**References:**

1. [Link to the specific SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68333287/8283848)

Comment: Possibly related: *[Bug with <pre><code> tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291128)*

Comment: What if `<strong>` is used instead of `<b>`?

Comment: @PeterMortensen won't work, in fact no inline HTML will work, as highlight.js now strips any unescaped html it finds in the code.

Comment: @Vega The formatting is working in the ***"Edit Mode"*** (Already mentioned that in my `Note` section)